# MVC 5 Routes - Using URL string einstead GUID

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Custom URL strng for friendly URL SEO.
Here is my model:

```
[Table("UserProfiles")]
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public string UrlSeo { get; set; }
}
```

So I need to do next things:
Using default routing like this `https://localhost/UserProfiles/Details/Guid_Here`. This working fine by default. Next I want to  display user url like this: `https://localhost/User_url_Seo_Here`
And one more thing: `https://localhost/UserProfiles/User_url_here`
So then I'm  Changing routes one of my models not working and giving me 400 bad request
Here is my controller example:

```
// GET: UserProfiles/Details/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    UserProfile userProfile = await db.UserProfiles.FindAsync(id);
    if (userProfile == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(userProfile);
}
```

No my routes:
If I'm Using routes like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
    name: "DetailUserProfile",
    url: "UserProfiles/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "UserProfiles",
        action = "Details",
        ident = UrlParameter.Optional
    }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

It removes action  name on  details but CRUD not working. If I use controller like this:

```
// GET: UserProfiles/View/5
public async Task<ActionResult> ViewProfile(string urlseo)
{
    if (urlseo == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    UserProfile userProfile = await db.UserProfiles.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UrlSeo == urlseo);
    if (userProfile == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(userProfile);
}
```

And route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
   name: "ViewUserProfile5",
   url: "UserProfiles/{action}/{urlseo}",
   defaults: new
   {
       controller = "UserProfiles",
       action = "ViewProfile",
       urlseo = UrlParameter.Optional
   }
);
```

I'm  recive HTTP Error 400.0 - Bad Request
But if I'm  changing `var = UrlParameter.Optional` it works fine, not so fine but controller with custom url working but CRUD operation stopped work.

Comment: Your 2nd `https://localhost/User_url_Seo_Here` cannot work because your providing only one segment and it will always go to the DefaultRoute and assume that `User_url_Seo_Here` is the controller name which will throw a 404 Not Found. You could make it work by using ` `https://localhost/UserProfiles/User_url_Seo_Here` and in the controller determining if the value is a `Guid` or not.

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to navigate to a method using either the users `Guid Id` or `string UrlSeo` values?, for example `.../UserProfiles/Details/xxx` where `xxx` can be either a `Guid` or a `string`?

Comment: One of way to  make it work  use different controllers one for operation with GUID other for using URL SEO is it write?

Comment: You could have different methods, but if you wanted a single method to accept both, then make the parameter `string id` and then use `Guid.TryParse()` to check if the value of `id` is a `Guid` or not, and use the appropriate query to get the `UserProfile`

Comment: Thank a lot Stephen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not writing on C# anymore but faced one mistake in my old code and know solution:
5 Years after but:
Problem is that I'm waiting for GUID as id but passing string, inspiration came from node.js, python flask and java spring boot.
So if I turn to this:

```
/ GET: UserProfiles/Details/5
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(String? id)
{
if (id == null)
{
    return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
}
UserProfile userProfile = await db.UserProfiles.FindAsync(id);
if (userProfile == null)
{
    return HttpNotFound();
}
return View(userProfile);
}
```

It will work, thanks for comments but no one noticed this thing.